# GET and POST values not correctly mapped to method signature

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to build a form for a many-to-many relationship, where Teams can belong to any number of institutions, and institutions can hold any number of teams.

My current problem is related to assigning an institution to a team. The idea is to have a select box on the team form with an "add this institution" button, which triggers an "addInstitution" action in the controller. I have put all institutions into a ViewBag SelectList object, and this is correctly displayed in the Team/Edit action, along with all currently assigned institutions:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddInstitution", "Team", new { team = Model.ID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        Add to institution:
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("institution", (SelectList)ViewBag.Institutions)
    </div>    

    <div>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Institutions)
            {
                <li>@item.InstitutionName</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>

}
```

Displaying this information works fine. However, I was under the impression that any GET or POST parameters (team and institution) would be mapped to the parameters of the receiving method, which is why I put team in the form objectRouteValues, while I expect the institution to be supplied by the select box value:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string AddInstitution(Team team, Institution institution)
{
    return "team: " + team.ID + ", institution: " + institution.ID;
}
```

Both of the parameters in this method are null. Anyone knows why they are not correctly mapped to the method signature?

Bonus question: is this your preferred strategy for building a form for a many-to-many relationship, or is there a better way?

Comment: I've discovered that it actually works if I substitute the object identifiers with "int" in the method signature. This means I can find the objects in the dbcontext, and update them that way. But shouldn't it be able to instantiate objects from ID's given the signature?

Comment: I think you cannot deal with two model on the same view the way you used it

Comment: I am only assigning one model to the view, and a SelectList to the ViewBag.

Comment: But the actions work only with models or primitive types

Comment: Okay, so basically I should just accept that the incoming data are int's? Or is it a better strategy to build a ViewModel for this purpose?

Comment: @HaroldSmith could you please add your model into your question?

Comment: Can you make one model ....I mean is there a way that you can add Institution as part of your model Team like a property. In that case your problem will go away

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm not entirely clear on everything. I would really like to see how your model for the page is defined.

You could use [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to get everything that was on the form.

```
public string AddInstitution(Team team, FormCollection frm)
{
 //you should just get frm["institution"] but I'm not super sure, 
 //put a breakpoint and use the immediate window and inspect frm.
}
```

The correct way to do this is to **represent everything your view has inside the ViewModel**. You should only have ONE ViewModel per page.

Comment: Even in case the View has strongly type model ?

Comment: @ewvfwrwwvw what do you mean? The ViewModel is a model or plain class (no behaviour usually) that represents the view. So it should encompass all that the view has. You could have a separate **data model** that represents your database schema and the convert between the two.

Comment: I meant , It's an alternative. What's the root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

The Team and Institution parameters of your action are classes. You have to provide input fields for at least one property of that classes, not for the class/parameter name itself.

For example, to bind to the Id property of the team parameter, you can use a hidden field named `team.Id`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddInstitution", "Team", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("team.Id", Model.ID)
}
```

For the institution parameter the same rule applies. You have to call the field `institution.Id`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("institution.Id", (SelectList)ViewBag.Institutions)
```

That way, the modelbinder will create instances of your classes and assign the form values to the Id property.